Not able to get default cookie value when website is loaded with JSOUP, Chrome console is showing no internet
I'm trying to get default cookie value when website gets loaded 1st time
But when I open Network tab and try to re-load page, always getting "No Internet" error message
After closing console and loading website; it just loads fine

Is this bug with Chrome ( Version 130.x.y. + Mac OS 11.5.2 )

How to get default cookie value when website gets loaded ? ( provided Chrome console is working )


I'm trying to achieve below
String url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/";

Connection.Response response = null;
int MAX_TIMEOUT = 60000;
String cookieHardCodedValue_First = TBD;
 
try {
    response =
        Jsoup.connect(url)
             .timeout(MAX_TIMEOUT)
             .userAgent(userAgentValue)
             .header("Cookie", cookieHardCodedValue_First)
             .method(Connection.Method.GET)
             .execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


